# How to go to another page by clicking a button in React

Tags: reactjs, button, navigation

I have created a navbar in React but I also want to use a button to return the user to the home page. I have created the button but don’t know where to go from here.

BlackWhite.js

```
export default function BlackWhite() {
  const handleClick = () => {};
  return (
    <div className="BlackWhite">
      <h1>Black and white</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Back to homepage</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import BlackWhite from './pages/BlackWhite';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Color from './pages/Color';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/BlackWhite" element={<BlackWhite />} />
          <Route path="/Color" element={<Color />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useNavigate()` hooks.

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";

export default function BlackWhite() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleClick = () => {
        navigate('/');
    };
    return (
        <div className="BlackWhite">
            <h1>Black and white</h1>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Back to homepage</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

or You can use `Link` to navigate. `<Link to='/' />` is just same as`<a href=''>`. You can customize it.

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function BlackWhite() {

    return (
        <div className="BlackWhite">
            <h1>Black and white</h1>
            <Link to='/'>Back to homepage</Link>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function BlackWhite() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate("/home"); // Replace "/home" with the actual URL of your home page
  };

  return (
    <div className="BlackWhite">
      <h1>Black and white</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Back to homepage</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";

export default function BlackWhite() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleClick = () => {
        navigate('/');
    };
    return (
        <div className="BlackWhite">
            <h1>Black and white</h1>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Back to homepage</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```